# Which Vim plugin autocompletes Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, vim, plugins, autocomplete

Some time ago, when I was using Janus, I could autocomplete Ruby code. I don't mean "autocomplete" in the sense of the `SuperTab` plugin, I mean, for example, when you type

```
collection.ea
```

And then hit the `Tab` key, you get

```
collection.each do ||

end
```

And your cursor is positioned between the `||`. You could also do the similar when defining a method.

Does anyone know how that plugin is called?. The problem is that I'm not using Janus anymore, so I don't have that plugin anymore. I looked at every plugin in the Janus documentation, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be [Snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)?

You can find Ruby snippets for Snipmate [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets).

Just do:

```
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets.git
rake deploy_local
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you so much :D